# Ionic AppVersion getPackageName() returns undefined

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to use the `getPackageName()` function in the [AppVersion plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-version/) but it is returning undefined on both iOS and Android. Is there another way to access the app package name in Ionic?

Current code:

```
  this.platform.ready()
    .then((readySource) => {
       this.appVersion.getPackageName()
         .then(packageName => {
            alert(packageName)
            this.market.open(packageName)
         })
         .catch(error => {
            console.log(`Error getting app package name. Error: ${error}`)
         })
     })
```

The package name is defined in the config.xml file like this:

```
<widget android-packageName="com.company.appId" id="io.ionic.starter" ios-CFBundleIdentifier="com.company.iosAppId" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public plt: Platform) {
    this.plt.ready().then((readySource)=>{
      this.packageName = AppVersion.getPackageName();
   })
}
```

Comment: This returns undefined too. The getAppVersion call works in `ionViewDidLoad` and in my regular function

Comment: did you add the plugin? https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-version/

Comment: Yes, it is added. The other functions like `getAppVersion()` and `getAppName()` are working as expected.

Comment: `getPackageName()` isn't static, I get "Property doesn't exist on type AppVersion"

Comment: import { AppVersion } from 'ionic-native'; ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170310/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-ben-steeves).